# Authentication with Azure using OAuth2 for an ionic mobile app

Tags: angularjs, azure, oauth-2.0, ibm-mobilefirst

I have been trying to retrieve the token from Azure AD by posting in the username and password using the HTTP angular service. Unfortunately, I always get this error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) 
It complains the following: "**The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'**"

Does anyone have any idea what this is happening?

This is my login controller and I have set up my Azure AD already.

function access() {

```
  var username = vm.username.trim();
  var password = vm.password.trim();

  requestAccessToken(username, password);
}
```

function requestAccessToken(username, password){

```
  var base_url = 'https://login.windows.net';

  var client_id = "35d16a1c-3f01-402a-9346-ee13b0aa2ba0";

  var params = '?grant_type=password&client_id=' + client_id + '&username=' + username + '&password=' + password;

  var path = "/4397b89d-d9d7-4d27-9cac-f7ae0ff0d880/oauth2/token";
  //var path = "/common/oauth2/token"; we have tried this one too

  var url = base_url + path + params;
  $http.post(url).success(getAccessTokenSuccess).error(getAccessTokenFailure);
}

function getAccessTokenSuccess(data, status, header, config) {
  console.log('data: ', data);
}

function getAccessTokenFailure(data, status, header, config) {
  console.log('data: ', data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to send `grant_url` in the request body (that implies the HTTP request is probably a POST), not as a query parameter, which is what you are doing.